# JOptionPane showMessageDialog request focus in console program

Tags: java, swing, console-application, joptionpane

I have a program that runs in the CLI, but uses a JOptionPane in order to display a popup menu to alert the user of an event. I have noticed that when the showMessageDialog method is called, the resulting popup menu does not focus automatically.

Is there a way to request focus for the popup dialog box? I have tried calling requestFocus on the JOptionPane, but to no avail.

Here is some sample code.

```
System.out.println("Backing up...");
//backUp();
Component frame = null;
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
jop.showMessageDialog(frame, "Backup complete. Ready for encryption.");
```

I apologize if this is a repost, but I haven't been able to find a working answer so far.

Comment: I just tried your code and it automatically got focus! To test, just hit "Enter" and see if the popup doesn't disappear.

Comment: @mohsenmadi It doesn't do it if I'm in another window, which is the issue. Normally I can get around this by calling `requestFocus()`, but I can't seem to do that since `showMessageDialog` is static, and calling `jop.requestFocus()` doesn't take effect because `showMessageDialog` pauses the thread.

Comment: Still couldn't reproduce! I just tried `try { Thread.sleep(2000); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Back...");} catch (InterruptedException e) {}` to give time to focus on other windows. Result? Still got focus when the popup displayed! I am running on a Mac - maybe different systems give different behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `JDialog` and make a call to [setAlwaysOnTop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)) passing `true`.

```
JOptionPane jop = new JOptionPane();
JDialog dlog = jop.createDialog(null, "Backup complete. Ready for encryption.");
dlog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);//make JDialog on top of other windows
dlog.setVisible(true);
```

The above works on `Windows`, but note that this behavior may be platform dependent (see docs - you can check if this is supported via the [isAlwaysOnTopSupported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#isAlwaysOnTopSupported()) method)